# How to send saved contact list by post method in to server in android ?

Tags: android, android-contacts

I am creating one android project. I want to send phone contact list to the server using post method. I searched it badly but did not get any solution for this. can anybody help me? Any suggestions.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names.html ..check this link for retrieving contacts ..and send it through jsonstringer or namevalue pairs through http.